# Issue with Java: Minecraft Launcher in Kubuntu doesn't recognize Java 8 JRE!

Tags: kubuntu, java, minecraft

I'm using the .jar launcher, since that's my favorite one to use, but I've noticed a weird problem. When I do `"sudo update-alternatives --config java"` and select Java 8 JRE and open up the launcher, the launcher still claims that I'm using Java 7 instead, and this is really frustrating because I need to use Java 8 to use several mods I have installed.
*Edit*: I would like to add that my Kubuntu version is Kubuntu 16.10 (latest). I've also tried deleting the .minecraft folder and reopening the launcher but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved:

I did dpkg --list and found the packages oracle-java7-set-default and oracle-java7-installer and I removed them using sudo apt-get --purge remove. Now the Minecraft launcher has no choice but to use Java 8.